# How many clients should be open using redis-om? During production and dev?

Tags: redis

When i'm in development mode, it seems like everytime I close and reopen the window (without killing it), I get another client added in the Redis insight count.

Is this how it should be working? Or did i configure something incorrectly?

How will this look in production/live site. If i have 30 visitors at a time, will I have 30 clients open?

Comment: Close and reopen the window of what?

Comment: @AnkitSahay Just close and open the browser window. In this case : Chrome.